# How do I remove files from parent directory?

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to remove the files inside many folders

For example:

I am in `project` folder and I want to remove file with range of `junk-5.jpg` to `junk-10.jpg`.

`junk-5` and `junk-10` are within different folders....

I have tried `rm -r junk-5.jpg` in project folder but it said no such file or directory.

Are there any faster way to do this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find ~/project/ \( -name "junk-[56789].jpg" -o -name "junk-10.jpg" \) -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bash 4+:

```
shopt -s globstar
rm ./**/junk{5..10}.jpg
```